# Play a beep sound when touching a button

Tags: java, android, audio, playback, onclicklistener

I am new in android programming, 
I want to play a beep sound when clicking on a button.

I have onClickListener in my application which do something, I want to play a beep when button is clicked!

How to play a beep sound when touching a button?

```
            layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        if(C=="1") { C="2"; s2=s2+ex;}
                        else { C="1"; s1=s1+ex;}

                    }
                });
```

how to do that with detailes like where to copy my beep.mp3 or beep.wav sound and codes and ...
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very good tutorial
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidMedia/article.html

Also, next time, please consider Google.
https://www.google.com/search?q=play+sound+android

This tutorial is the second result.

another good one: http://java.dzone.com/articles/playing-sounds-android